# Efficient way of generating "item-item distance rank matrix" in MATLAB?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have a 1000-by-3 matrix `X` containing 1000 datapoints in the 3D space. I can easily generate the item-item Mahalanobis distance matrix in MATLAB:

```
X = random(1000, 3);
distMat = pdist(X, 'mahalanobis');
distMat = squareform(distMat);
```

where the (`i`, `j`)-th entry is the distance between point `i` and point `j`.

Now I wish to have a similar matrix whose (`i`, `j`)-th entry is the rank of point `i` among all points based on the distance to point `j`. So I call it "item-item distance rank matrix."

My idea is to just sort each row of `distMat` and construct this desired matrix with the sorting indices, but this requires 1000 sorting operations. I believe there's a much more efficient way.

Comment: Those 1000 sorting operations can be vectorized, so they should not take too long. `[~, ind] = sort(matrix, 2);` gives the indices of the sorting of each row of `matrix`